# How to Git Merge while preserving changes in master?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have wordpress theme, inside a git repo, which i modified to suit my needs. Now a version update of the theme has been released. I created a new branch for the theme update and committed the update there. Now I would like my changes in `master` branch to be preserved when merging.

But how?

When I merge the branch back to `master` with `git merge theme`, it overrides the changes I want to preserve!

So how shall I go about it?

Comment: How did you create the update branch?

Comment: Are you seeing conflicts or is it just overwriting your theme?

Comment: No conflicts. Simply overwriting. I can manually copy my changes back but that beats the purpose of Git.

Comment: I have been a git user for a little over a month now (mostly the basic add, commit, push and pull). I am just stepping into branch merging now; I hope I am not missing something (I have read the related Git book pages).

Comment: Ah wait. You branched off master _after_ you commited your theme changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you branched to `theme` *after* you commited your changes to the theme, they're already in the branched version (for git) and thus will be overwritten. But you can fix that. First, if you have already merged, your `theme` branch into `master`, go through `git log` (or use gitk) to find the commit at which master was *before* you merged in `theme` (`git reflog` might know this too). Run `git reset --hard $commitid`, where `$commitid` is the id of the commit you just found out. This is to undo the (bad) merge.

Then, still on master, you go through `git log` and find the first commit *before* you made the changes to the theme. Note down the commit ID and do, replacing `COMMITID` with the ID you just noted:

```
git checkout COMMITID
```

Git will utter something about detached HEAD and so on, but ignore that for now. Now you branch off again:

```
git checkout -b theme-new  # equivalent to git branch theme-new
```

This will give you a branch at the very same state as master was at `COMMITID`. Now you again download the new theme version and copy it into the repository. Commit that change. Switch back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Verify that master is on the last commit you made to it. Then do:

```
git merge theme-new
```

There might be conflicts, see [this helpful reference in the gitbook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts) to learn how to manage them. After you did the merge, you should have exactly what you wanted.

---

Why this works: You branched off master *after* you already committed your custom theme. By that, git assumes that in the *new* branch, the customized theme is already included. By copying the updated theme from *upstream* in (and committing that), you tell git that you want to completely overwrite your customized version with the version downloaded. On a merge, git looks for the latest common commit the two branches have (which includes your customization) and only applies any commits which have been made *after* that one.

Thus it'll apply the exact commit which overwrites the whole theme with the upstream version. You obvoiusly don't want that. By doing what I described above, you'll tell git that the *upstream* version was in fact created “parallel” to the one you created. So it'll be more careful and see how it can merge the changes in. I'll draw a nice diagram:

```
              G---H theme
             /
A---B---C---D       master
     \
      E---F         theme-new
```

Assume that commits `A` and `B` are your initial checkin of the data and any development prior to your theme customizations. Further assume that `C` is the commit where you customized your theme and `D` is something else. `G` and `H` are the commits you did in `theme` to download and apply the package from *upstream*, while `E` and `F` are in fact the same, just in another branch.

The difference between merging `theme` and `theme-new` into master is only the place where the branch actually diverges from `master`, which is crucial. As you can see, git assumes that your customization *is* included in `theme`, because you branched off *after* you customized. But in `theme-new`, git doesn't assume that, because you branched that off *before* the change. Thus, it'll try an actual merge with the customizations.

Comment: Oh that was brilliant! I wouldn't have figured this out all by myself just by RTFM. But thanks to you @Jonas Wielicki, I learned something new today! Thank you for the detailed explanation.